# Sending PHP Variables - setInterval only works once

Tags: php, ajax

I try to send two PHP, and one JS Variable to a different PHP Script.
I have not even basic understanding of JavaScript or Ajax, so I copied a bunch of stuff from different websites.

```
var timeInMs = Date.now();


function SendData(){
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'test2.php',
    data: {var1: timeInMs,var2: '<?= $var2; ?>', var3: '<?= $var3; ?>'}
});  
}

$(document).ready(function(){
 setInterval(SendData,5000);
});
```

So this is what I have now, and it kind of works.
It does the Job ones. Can you tell me what I have to change in order to have it repeat itself?
I saw on here, that most people have a "success" part in there Ajax Array, is that the reason?
I don't want anything to happen when it ran successfully.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? just repeating an API call every 5seconds?

Comment: I want to keep track of how long people stay on a specific site. At the end I want to update a value in the database.

Comment: are you not getting any errors from the console?

Comment: No, nothing on there